# Why is my rendered image in black & white?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am trying to get a Glow effect in the compositor. I added Node Math (Add)

[image]

And now my render is black&white. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Image output from your render layer node is composed of 3 seperate color channels that are mixed to show a full color image. The math node collapses these three different channels into three identical channels. Therefore there is no variation between them to display color.  You would need to split the channels using a Seperate RGB node, then do math on one or all, then recombine using a Combine RGB node.

Comment: Also try just using the Color Mix node and set its function to Add. This should do what you want.

Comment: @3pointedit please write your comment as an answer

Comment: I was going to do @cegatron that but I didn't have access to blender to include illustrations, which I felt made the answer sub par. So I just helped instead.

Answer (score 2):

Like [3pointedit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1218/3pointedit) already said in his comment, the problem is the math 
node.

An option to solve your problem is using the *Seperate RGBA* node for both pictures and use the math node for each channel seperately. Afterwards combine the channels again with the *Combine RGBA* node.

Or, again referring to [3pointedit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1218/3pointedit), use the Color Mix Node.